# There is a user appearing twice when a document is shared in SharePoint 2016

Tags: central-administration, user-accounts, domain, ad

I was not able to replicate this problem but this is what two users are reporting. When they go to [Share] a document/file uploaded in SharePoint 2016 Document Library, within the Share section they type in the user's username and it gives them 2 x same identical username but on different domain.

However, there is only *ONE* such usser account in the Domain and there is no others in other domains.I have reset the cach files on the client's browsers but same result.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you migrated your user from one domain to a new domain?

if So you can move your user from one domain to another domain.

You can use the below command to fix your problem

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "DomainA\JaneDoe" -Web https://webUrl

Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "DomainB\JaneDoe"
```

For more details please use below URL

[Move-SPUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Hi Buki,

Please mark it as answer if you satisfied and up  vote it.  it will help others too.

Comment: Hi @Rajat Sahani , I am new in the company but couldn't find a trace if the user has been migrated in the past. Never the less, one of the colleagues had to clear the CACHE on the SP Server side (unsure how this is done) and apparently fixed the problem.

Strange part was that the user only saw this behaviour on Internet Explorer, whilst other browser's were fine.